# Can I use a wifi bridge that has its own VPN connection?

Tags: wireless-networking, vpn

I will be staying in another country for several months. The home has an Internet access point and wifi router (one box). There may be an ethernet output but I'm not sure of that.

I want to be able to watch US streaming TV channels by connecting to a US-based VPN. My approach -- if this is possible -- would be to put a bridge on the wifi router and have that router automatically route device (e.g. streaming stick) traffic to the VPN in the US.

Does anyone have an suggestions on how I can do this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "a bridge on the wifi router" and "streaming stick"?

Comment: Are you subject to a host supplying internet and what do they say.

Comment: Essentially creating two networks is my goal, one of which would run traffic through the regular router normally, and the other running traffic via the US VPN. A bridge seemed like the best way to to that, in theory, but I'm not sure. By streaming stick I mean Roku, Google Chromecast, Apple TV, etc.

Comment: Yes, the host doesn't want me to muck with the router supplied by the ISP there.

Comment: I believe there are routers that can connect directly to VPN services. You should be able to plug your own router in downstream from the host's box without impacting their connection preferences. What research have you done and what have you tried?

Comment: @music2myear Yes, that's exactly what I'm hoping to do. My research has been surprisingly frustrating, or I'm using the wrong keywords!